# How to get @Url.Action value inside a controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `ASP.net core`

I can use an Html action inside a view

```
@Url.Action("GetOptions", "ControllerName", new { id="1"});
```

However I want to get a string value of it in the Controller.

e.g. something like

```
string Url= Url.Action("GetOptions", "ControllerName", new { id="1"}).ToString();
```

In previous versions of MVC you can reference the helper in the controller by

```
  UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

Basically what I want to do is generate a URL string representation in my controller

Comment: `Html.Action()` calls a controller method to return a view. Do you mean `Url.Action()`

Comment: Yes. fixed my post

Comment: `string url = Url.Action("GetOptions", "ControllerName", new { id = 1 });` will work

Comment: it does work. thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order for the route values to work correctly for me I had to use the static invocation of the url helpers

`UrlHelperExtensions.Action(Url, "Details", "Resellers", new { id = 1 })`

Edit: The shorthand way of writing this is:

`this.Url.Action("Details", "Resellers", new { id = 1 })`

Thanks @Learner.

Comment: Then you could have just called `this.Url.Action("Details", "Resellers", new { id = 1 })`